# Python: How to call doctest from within Visual Studio

Tags: python, visual-studio-2017

I am just starting out with Python, and have noticed that Visual Studio (2017) has Python as an project type.
I have doctests set up in my python scripts, and want to know how to call them from within the Visual Studio environment.

I have tried from the Interactive window which has the >>> prompt, and from the PackageManager Console, which has PM> prompt, but neither of these work.  I have tried typing "python -m doctest myfile.py", and have tried "doctest.testfile("myfile.py"), but I get errors unrelated to the doctest.

Can anyone explain how I do this?
I realise that there are Unit Tests in Visual Studio, but this is not the same thing.  I want to be able to run doctests that already exist in '.py' files.